# Linux newbie. Help. Stuck on some mode.

Tags: linux, terminal

Hi I am a new unix user and I have been stuck in the terminal in this mode: '>' I accidentally pressed ls` instead of ls and suddenly it went to '>' this mode. I just would like to ask how to exit from that mode? Thanks!

Comment: Hit controL+C or control+D.  It's waiting for you to complete the expression by typing another backtick (`).

Comment: Thank you all for all your responses. But I tried control + c on mac but it seems not to work. I pressed it already and nothing happens. Is there a command line I can type instead? I must add though that I am running through a server. Thanks!

Comment: Closed? Really? This is a pretty useful question...

Answer (score 3):

You escape by doing this - <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Or, if you are using a Mac, then - <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

If the above did not work close the tick <kbd>`</kbd> then hit enter.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But It seems not to work. I pressed it already and nothing happens. Is there a command line I can type instead? Thanks!

Comment: i didnt know your a mac user i updated

Comment: hey, I know this is an old thread, but I stumbled on it today looking for  a way out of 'bc' - calculator mode ( ctrl d ) . what is this mode for? when does it get used?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this shortcut CRTL+Z or CRTL+Q

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I tried control + c on mac but it seems not to work. I pressed it already and nothing happens. Is there a command line I can type instead? I must add though that I am running through a server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easy to fix: Hit Ctrl-C and you should be OK

Answer (score 0):

To abort some acidental command try: ctrl + c

Answer (score 0):

Try typing 'quit' or 'exit' (or even '?' or 'help').